# Dynamic Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to group my variables in a particular way

My data : blue column are IDs, red my data layout , green is my desired output

[image]

It groups all the A before the B then it Groups all the B before the next A And then groups the C

This is done for one ID, I would like this to happen for all Id( the information is dynamic for each id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering to the rows unless a column explicitly specifies that ordering.  Let me assume that such a column exists.

You want to identify groups and then bring them together.  A simple way is to use `lag()` to determine where changes occur and then take the value when a change occurs:

```
select col
from (select t.*,
             lag(col) over (partition by id order by ??) as prev_col
      from t
     ) t
where prev_col is null or prev_col <> col;
```

The `??` is the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: in the over clause  I should have a partition by clause in the event i have more than  id

Comment: yea i just put the  ID in the order by clause it worked , i checked for about 6 to 7 ids.   Thanks for showing me this logic

Comment: @RyanGomes . . . That is not guaranteed to work.  If this is important, then you need a column that specifies the ordering.  The fact that tables represent *unordered* sets is quite fundamental, and you will just have errors and frustration if you ignore this simple fact.

Comment: So this has worked for my data so far I have controlled the ordering by using a row_number function for each ID